# How can I create aar file in android studio 1.3.1 while I've made the project without activity

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I create `aar` file in android studio 1.3.1 while  I've made the project without activity and I have only one class in that.

Comment: you want to create or add a aar file

Comment: I want to create a `aar` file to use in another projects.